# Solr custom RequestHandler ClassNotFoundException

Tags: java, solr

I was following this tutorial - http://www.slideshare.net/searchbox-com/develop-a-solr-request-handler-plugin and built the required jar file in Netbeans then put it into the lib path and added the request handler to solrconfig.xml:

```
    <requestHandler name="/newendpoint" class="com.searchbox.DemoPlugin">
            <lst name="words">
                    <str name="word">body</str>
                    <str name="word">fish</str>
                    <str name="word">dog</str>
            </lst>
    </requestHandler>
```

I see the jar being loaded:

```
INFO  - 2015-02-06 12:32:21.903; org.apache.solr.core.SolrResourceLoader; Adding 'file:/data/solr/lib/DemoPlugin-1.0.jar' to classloader
```

But then I get an error when I try to restart solr:

```
ERROR - 2015-02-06 12:39:02.942; org.apache.solr.core.CoreContainer; Error creating core [test]: RequestHandler init failure
org.apache.solr.common.SolrException: RequestHandler init failure
        at org.apache.solr.core.SolrCore.<init>(SolrCore.java:873)
        at org.apache.solr.core.SolrCore.<init>(SolrCore.java:646)
        at org.apache.solr.core.CoreContainer.create(CoreContainer.java:491)
        at org.apache.solr.core.CoreContainer$1.call(CoreContainer.java:255)
        at org.apache.solr.core.CoreContainer$1.call(CoreContainer.java:249)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: org.apache.solr.common.SolrException: RequestHandler init failure
        at org.apache.solr.core.RequestHandlers.initHandlersFromConfig(RequestHandlers.java:172)
        at org.apache.solr.core.SolrCore.<init>(SolrCore.java:792)
        ... 8 more
Caused by: org.apache.solr.common.SolrException: Error loading class 'com.searchbox.DemoPlugin'
        at org.apache.solr.core.SolrResourceLoader.findClass(SolrResourceLoader.java:490)
        at org.apache.solr.core.SolrResourceLoader.findClass(SolrResourceLoader.java:421)
        at org.apache.solr.core.SolrCore.createInstance(SolrCore.java:543)
        at org.apache.solr.core.SolrCore.createRequestHandler(SolrCore.java:616)
        at org.apache.solr.core.RequestHandlers.initHandlersFromConfig(RequestHandlers.java:158)
        ... 9 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.searchbox.DemoPlugin
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)
        at java.net.FactoryURLClassLoader.loadClass(URLClassLoader.java:789)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
        at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
        at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:274)
        at org.apache.solr.core.SolrResourceLoader.findClass(SolrResourceLoader.java:474)
        ... 13 more
```

I confess I'm no java expert so am wondering if I've missed something obvious, or mechanics have changed since the tutorial was created, expanding the DemoPlugin jar it has the required com/searchbox/DemoPlugin.class file in, so I'm at a bit of a loss.

Any pointers appreciated.

Si

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have tried this tutorial and I can confirm that it works as explained.

For you I can only assume the jar is not loaded where it should (even if the log sais the classloader gets it).

I have put the jar in {solr.home}/{core.name}/lib.

A little more info on how to deploy new plugins into solar is [here](https://wiki.apache.org/solr/SolrPlugins).

Try to use a solr.xml file and configure there exactly where the plugin should be loaded from.

Comment: Thanks, not sure if it was permissions or locations but put it in the lib folder for the core in question and now works fine.